# Krishna's presence in Puranas

Tags: shiva, krishna, shiva-lingam

If Krishna was born in 3228 BCE , how was he present during the Puranas when he fought against Shiva due to Banasura and Anirudha's fight ?

Comment: Puranas are compiled and seperated by Vyasa who is contemporary to Lord Krishna, hence Puranas mention Krishna...

Comment: @Tezz Then how come Puranas mention Buddhist workplaces if they were written by Vyasa before Buddha?

Comment: @Ajay There might be previous Buddhas before Gautama Buddha... also Lord Vishnu took Buddha Avatara also during Tripura Dahana...

Comment: @Tezz So, Jainism too?

Answer (score 1):

The purans were created after mahabharata.
originally purans are considred smriti(what has been remembred) no nessasory that at what time they were written things existed or taken place. take the example of samudra manthana story it took place very before than purans so,krishna was there but not at the time when Mahabharata was written down by lord ved vyasa as it discribes the departure of lord krishna from earth when striked arrow by a hunter and his material body died.

> http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16004.htm

So,in short purans show the smritis(what has been remembred) and they are smriti  as the story of fight of banasur was there from harivamsa parva of mahabharat to puranic age carried as smriti.

> **smriti**—
>   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smriti

Comment: additional refrences to mahabharata and wikipedia are now been given!!
if more comment it ;)

Comment: I have now come to the section where Krishna's presence is explained. He comes to Lord Shiva to ask for blessings and boons. Vyasa mentions Krishna :)